# How get data from asp.net web api in asp.net mvc controller in the same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

i need to write website, that must have private part in single page application and  public part that  must be in classic style(to the best indexing by searching engines) with Ajax support without usage CORS or JSONP. All logic must be in service (RESTful) style, for future mobile apps support. So i decide to use ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API in one project(to prevent CORS or JSONP), i planning to use asp.net mvc controllers to return template html for private part and whole html for public part. I don't want to put any logic to asp.net mvc controllers except get some data (dictionary collections) for public part views. So is see two possible solution  for that.

1. Create ApiController and try to get data from it method

   - Don't like that, because it destroy RESTful style and SoC (it's need to pass IUnityOfWofk implementation to asp.net mvc controller constructor under DI, to redirect it to constructor of ApiController)
   - Like that because it don't need to spent time to http request same host (localhost).
2. Get data under http request to ApiController in MVC controller.

   - Like that beacuse RESTful and SoC is OK.
   - Don't like that becuase it spent time to http request to same host(localhost).

My questions are:

1. What else possible solutions can be to solve my task (in .Net platform) ?
2. How http request to same host (localhost) in asp.net mvc controller  may influence the delay in time for the client browser (public part), it is criticaly for response time ?
3. What is the best solution 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to factor out your logic from the Web API controller to a separate class model and use it both in the MVC and the Web API controllers, e.g. by injecting the instances of the relevant logic classes into the controllers. You'd also be able to share the Unit of Work.

Of course, this adds another layer of complexity, but at the same time leads to a better Separation of Concerns. After all, MVC and Web API are only a way to present your logic to specific clients. In case of Web API, the main responsibility of the Web API layer is to create a RESTful interface to your logic; handling the logic itself is not a task of the Web API layer if you are very strict.

I'd favor this approach over the others as these approaches have some downsides (numbers as in your question):

1. **Create ApiController**: you need to mimic the Web API environment very well. Though this is possible, it also means that changes on the Web API side of things will have an effect on the implementation of your logic.
2. **Make a HTTP request to the Web API**:

   - Though a request to the same server in the MVC controllers might be relatively quick and therefore not critical, it will take some time that is not necessary if you can just have a call to some shared classes.
   - Also, the HTTP request adds a point where your system might break.
   - In addition, you wouldn't be able to share a Unit of Work with the Web API.